# Генерация ссылки на видео в youtube

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Я знаком с php из далека, пока не претендую углубляться в него, но связь с сервером мне нужно, что-то элементарное передать, обработать, забрать я смогу написать, вот кстати что мне нужно: подать запрос на сервер, и изьять от туда ссылку на источник видео с ютуба, которая выглядит примерно так: [Видео](https://r4---sn-3c27sn7z.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=22&signature=6E2E86538309ED3985D452B5290BE9ABBBE5931C.4A5F7EA65953B4088A252C4B6E2A4D6196707ACA&dur=1776.372&ei=7asvXNDzMMbK7ATrzL2gBg&lmt=1540311994990890&ip=92.50.142.70&expire=1546649677&id=o-APcY6JHlR6FePH9LYr8UYI1pVRa8VH-R2wgiyiiX1Sjo&c=WEB&key=cms1&sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&source=youtube&pl=23&txp=5531432&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&fvip=4&ipbits=0&mime=video%2Fmp4&video_id=Bey4XXJAqS8&title=4K%20VIDEO%20ultrahd%20hdr%20sony%204K%20VIDEOS%20demo%20test%20nature%20relaxation%20movie%20for%204k%20oled%20tv&rm=sn-045oxu-045l7z,sn-n8vdk7z&req_id=3a81321764b9a3ee&redirect_counter=2&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=31.148.135.164&mm=29&mn=sn-3c27sn7z&ms=rdu&mt=1546632744&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAxLmticDAxKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE)

Получил я её с помощью добавления "ss" перед youtube.com, вышло ssyoutube.com, имея ссылку на видео с ютубе, можно скачать его с помощью этого же ss, там оно берет видео с источника, узнать сам источник можно скачав это видео (либо отменив установку) и в загрузках посмотреть от куда было скачало.

Все бы ничего, если бы этот источник не менялся со временем, так как я могу получить ссылку на источник зная лишь только ссылку на видео в ютубу?

Comment: Использовать youtube-dl

Comment: @andreymal я понимаю, но мне уж никак не хочеться его встраивать, думал может где есть сервис по типу php принял вернул.

Comment: Тогда, думаю, ничто не должно мешать распарсить этот самый ssyoutube

Comment: @andreymal повторюсь, я в этом не сильно, мне задача не по сайту нужна, а именно получить запрос с сервера.

Comment: Какой запрос с какого сервера? О чём речь вообще? Вроде же изначально речь была о получении ссылки на видео?

Comment: Не обращайте внимания на запрос, мне нужно получить именно с ссылки на видео ссылку на источник, а уже отправить себе я бы и сам смог.

Comment: Стоп, давайте конкретизируем: что такое «ссылка на видео» и что такое «ссылка на источник»?

Comment: @andreymal видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8, источник - https://is.gd/h3sqA8

Comment: Как из первой ссылки получить вторую ссылку, я вам уже написал: используйте youtube-dl или обращайтесь к ssyoutube.com, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: @andreymal youtube.dl мне не подходит, а как достать из ssyoutube.com я не знаю, вот и спросил.